# Retry for specific exception in Reactor

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have microservices application. For collaborating each service uses async messaging. I know, that spring data jpa uses optimistic lock by default. But in case of this lock in methods called  not by user, but by another service (in my example there are validation services, that can update status of object to valid or non valid) I want to handle exception and retry to update object. Also I had to use webflux stack on this microservice. Now i have such code:

```
public void updateStatus(String id, EventStatus status) {
    eventRepository.findById(id)
            .doOnNext(eventDocument -> {
                eventDocument.setStatus(status);
                eventRepository.save(eventDocument).subscribe();
            }).doOnError(OptimisticLockingFailureException.class, exception -> { //Retry in 2 sec if optimistic lock occurs on update
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                updateStatus(id, status);
            })
            .subscribe();
}
```

I don't like recursion here. Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: You could use the `retry` operator. However it's seems there are several issues with your code. Do you use webflux? Why do you subscribe manually?

Comment: @lkatiforis This service method is called by callback on Kafka message. Not by controller. That's why i am using subscribe manually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following retries every 2 seconds in case `OptimisticLockingFailureException` is thrown.

```
private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

public void updateStatus(String id, EventStatus status) {
    eventRepository.findById(id)
            .map(eventDocument -> {
                eventDocument.setStatus(status);
                return eventDocument;
            })
            .flatMap(event -> Mono.defer(() -> eventRepository.save(eventDocument)
                    .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(MAX_ATTEMPTS, Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                            .filter(t -> t instanceof OptimisticLockingFailureException))))
            .subscribe();
}
```